# Генерация кнопок в панели навигации для каждого существующего якоря

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтоб кнопки в панели навигации создавались автоматически для каждого имеющегося на странице якоря?

Якоря создаются сейчас автоматом для каждого тега `<p>`:

```
<div id="object_data_body">
<table>
    <tr class="link_group_header"><td colspan="3"><p>Заголовок 1</p></td></tr>
    <tr class="link_group_header"><td colspan="2"><p>Заголовок 2</p></td></tr>
    <tr class="link_group_header"><td colspan="2"><p>Заголовок 3</p></td></tr>
    <tr class="link_group_header"><td colspan="2"><p>Заголовок 4</p></td></tr>
</table>
```

```
//********Генерация якорей на заголовках**********//

//Берем все заголовки заключенные в тег "p" и помещенные в класс "link_group_header", и добавляем к ним якоря
$(function(){
$('.link_group_header p').each(function(Index){
    $(this).wrap("<section class='zagol' id='link_"+Index+"'></section>");
})


//********Генерация блока навигации в хедере**********//

var part_1 = '<a href="';//просто отрывок общего куска html 1
var part_2 = '#link_1';//линк для перехода из панели навигации
var part_3 = '" class="scrollto hint--bottom" data-hint="';//просто отрывок общего куска html 3
var part_4 = 'Заголовок 1';//подсказка для кнопки перехода
var part_5 = '"><li><img src="/images/bullet.png"></li></a>';//просто отрывок общего куска html 5

var a_link = part_1 + part_2 + part_3 + part_4 + part_5;//собираем общий кусок html из компонентов выше.

var generate_slide = document.createElement ('div'); generate_slide.id = 'full_body_slide';//создаем новый див
document.getElementById ("object_data_body").appendChild (generate_slide);//добавляем новый див в конец блока с контентом

//составляем конструкцию панельки для навигации по заголовкам и кладем ее в созданный див
$(generate_slide).html('<div id="slide_mnu_1" class="box-crew"></div>'); 
$('#slide_mnu_1').html('<span><div id="slide_mnu_2" class="bulets_1"></div></span>');
$('#slide_mnu_2').html('<ul id="slide_mnu_ul"></ul>');
$('#slide_mnu_ul').html(a_link);

var mass_zagol = document.getElementsByClassName("zagol");//получаем массив из заголовков
var mass_zagol_length = mass_zagol.length;//получаем длину массива с заголовками

var id_only = document.getElementsByClassName("zagol")[0].id;// забираем id у одного из элементов массива

//Задаем условия, при панель навигации будет скрываться и показываться
if ($('.zagol').length < 1) {
$('#full_body_slide').hide();
}else{
$('#full_body_slide').show();
}
document.getElementById('#full_body_slide').style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

код в jsfiddle [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/malefikus13/hwmj2m2o/).

Comment: Почему, используя JQ, вы пишете так: `var generate_slide = document.createElement ('div')`, можно заменить на `var generate_slide = $('<div>')`

Comment: на примере в jsfiddle, панель навигации всплывает при наведении курсора в правом верхнем углу. :) Вдруг, кто не заметит просто :)

Comment: я только учусь :) По  этому и допускаю такие погрешности :)

Comment: @ThisMan, потому что `document.createElement` гораздо быстрее может))